# Revoking of ActiveMQ Message

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

On a transaction failure, Is it possible to **revoke posted message** from queue in activemq?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question lacks context, and will likely be closed. Please edit it to explain more about your situation, and how you use ActiveMQ, In particular: What do theses messages mean? Why do you want to "revoke" the message? What should happen with it in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Simply catch any exception and commit the transaction regardless of processing result.

If you want a rollback to always discard the message, simply use non persistent messages. They will disappear instead of ending up on a DLQ. Make sure you turn off redelivery as well.

Comment: Nahh.. hard to tell by the question what really is asked.